# how to show docxfile of database into my webpage?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have a database.i am saving my files path in the database..my filespath is in my hard drive..now i want to show my docxfile in my webpages..in my docxfile there may be some tables,may be any pictures..most wiil be some text in a big table..i want to show the data in my webpages same as the docxfile..how to do it??can anyone give me any suggestion??i am using asp.net with c#...

i have seen here some code to read data from file..but don't know whether it will show the tables where the data is inside like text....

```
@{
var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Persons.txt");
Array userData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Reading Data from a File</h1>
@foreach (string dataLine in userData) 
{
foreach (string dataItem in dataLine.Split(',')) 
{
@dataItem <text>&nbsp;</text>}
<br>
}

</body>
```

Comment: The code you have shown is from MVC project, if you want to read the file and then display it, you better use some 3rd party library such as "Docx" or some other (u can search on codeplex.com). If you just want to display the full contents of the file, then you can use Response object as indicated here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1547457.aspx But it is not guaranteed in Response case, as some times the browser will not display the file, but will show download dialogue, and some times it will show the file either in new window or current window

Comment: i just want to show the data in my webpages just like the way data is stored in docx file..

Comment: I indicated 2 techniques above, 1st one is not easy you have to learn to use a 3rd party library & you have to write a lot of code 2 get the information piece by piece from word document & then display it in web page, but it gives you 100% power of controlling & displaying content, once it is extracted from word file. 2nd option tries to display the full contents of file in web browser & I have tested it in Internet Explorer check the forums.asp.net link I have sent to you, but problem with this approach is, other browsers or some times IE show download instead of displaying the file